# How do I Display a Dynamic Message Based on Form Values in a Django Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to display different text based on the checked radio button/form value in a Django template, but I'm not sure how I can get a hold of the value and use it.

I tried using the value of the form passed up from the view, but that doesn't update on input change.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="radio_choice">Radio Choices</label>
  <br />
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="radio"
          name="radio_choice"
          id="radio-choice-one"
          value="RCO"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-choice-one">Radio Choice One</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="radio"
          name="radio_choice"
          id="radio-choice-two"
          value="RCT"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-choice-two">Radio Choice Two</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="radio"
          name="radio_choice"
          id="radio-choice-three"
          value="RCTh"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-choice-three">Radio Choice Three</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <small class="text-black-50">
      {% if form.radio_choice.value == 'RCO' %}
          <b>Radio Choice One</b> - Some text about choice one
      {% elif form.radio_choice.value == 'RCT' %}
          <b>Radio Choice Two</b> - Some text about choice two
      {% elif form.radio_choice.value == 'RCTh' %}
          <b>Radio Choice Three</b> - Some text about choice three
      {% endif %}
  </small>
</div>
```